# JPA annoted entities to POJO

Tags: android, jpa, jaxb, pojo

I have generated JPA enties class annoted with JAXB annotations using netbeans and I what to uses theses classes on my android project  but android plateform doesn't support jaxb annotation. so i need to get back simple POJO classes from those entities to port them in my android project and annotate them using Simple framework  because my android application should communicate with web services using xml. How can i get back to Pojo class without manually edit copied JPA entities?

Comment: You can map class with table without using annotation, you have to map them using xml, if you do this way your pojos will be free from EE specific class hence can be used in android project.

Comment: netbeans always maps existing database table class annoted classes